# GNOME 3 two keyboard shortcuts for the same action

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I would like to have two keyboard shortcuts associated to the same action. Is it possible to use a list of shortcuts for that?

I get a single value/shortcut if I execute:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
```

but, could that be a list? (a pair of shortcuts). I have tried, without success:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down \
      "['shortcut_0', 'shortcut_1']"
```

Executing that command does not throw an error, however, none of the elements in the list end-up working.

Note that I am trying to avoid creating a new "custom shortcut", in which I could specify a command which does the thing that I want (i.e.: lower the volume down), but with a different shortcut. I would like to keep all shortcuts associated to the "official" `gsettings`.

**Using**: GNOME 3.20. Although I wouldn't mind an answer if it works in a more recent GNOME version.

Comment: No, if you use `dconf` to alter that key value you'll see it's of type `string` (_not_ an array of strings) which means that particular key accepts only a single value.

Comment: @don_crissti Sad to hear that... :-( Thanks. Consider adding your answer here. Hope one they they will change that!

Comment: I don't think they will ever change that since the vast majority of people out there only need one shortcut. Also, keep in mind that custom shortcuts that you add via _settings_ interface are also added to the `dconf` database (hence `gsettings` ...)

Comment: @don_crissti how do you see the type of `dconf` key?

Comment: @anatolytechtonik - that's a [separate question now](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/490880/22142), if no one else answers it in 48 hours I'll do it.