# How to get the type of a certain dconf key?

Tags: command-line, dconf

How do I get the type of a `dconf`/`gsettings` key via command line ?
I know I can visually inspect keys types and values via the gui tool `dconf-editor` e.g.  the key `num-workspaces` under the schema `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` is of type `integer`:

[image]

I'd like to be able to get the type only in CLI via a command or script.

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

```
gsettings range org.gnome.Evince auto-reload
```

and you get :

```
type b
```

Comment: Yes, I know about `gsettings range ...` but it's sort of meh because in some cases the output is completely meaningless (to someone not familiar with _GVariant_ types)... see my updated example. I was hoping there's a tool/script that prints the type just like `dconf-editor` does but I guess there's no such thing...

Comment: the meaning of the `b`, `i`, etc. types is (kind of) documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-format-strings.html). Such a tool would be almost as complex as cdecl ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use dbus.
I am not with gnome so `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` is not available for me but with xfce ...
There is a utility like gsettings name xfconf-query.

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/workspace_count
```

give 4 but not the type.

```
dbus-send --session \
          --print-reply \
          --dest=org.xfce.Xfconf /org/xfce/Xfconf \
            org.xfce.Xfconf.GetProperty \
            string:xfwm4 \
            string:/general/workspace_count

method return time=1547386790.562285 sender=:1.8 -> destination=:1.73 serial=289 reply_serial=2
   variant       int32 4
```

The answer is better to someone not familiar with GVariant types